# Restoring two tensorflow models in the same graph

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to restore two pre-trained models (identical architecture, different initialization) into the same tensorflow graph (e.g. for the purpose of computing adversarial examples that fool both models).

In a nutshell: I am able to restore the two models in different scopes and make correct predictions. But then I get an InvalidArgumentError when attempting to compute loss gradients. The error persists when attempting to re-compute the predictions I could successfully compute prior to evaluating the gradients.

Concretely, I have a list of model checkpoints

```
models_ckpts = [model_chkpt0, model_chkpt1]
```

I then declare two models in separate scopes (the model is the standard ResNet18 from https://github.com/MadryLab/cifar10_challenge/blob/master/model.py)

```
from model import Model
models = []
for k, path in enumerate(models_ckpts):
  with tf.variable_scope('model_%03i' % k):
    models.append(Model(mode='eval'))
```

I use the following function to restore them:

```
def restore_collection(path, scopename, sess):
  variables = {v.name: v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scopename)}
  for var_name, _ in tf.train.list_variables(path):
    try:
      var_value = tf.train.load_variable(path, var_name)
      target_var_name = '%s/%s:0' % (scopename, var_name)
      target_variable = variables[target_var_name]
      sess.run(target_variable.assign(var_value))
    except:
      pass
```

I then start a session and restore the two models using the restore_collection function above

```
sess = tf.Session()
for k, path in enumerate(models_ckpts):
  restore_collection(path, scopename='model_%03i' % k, sess=sess)
```

I can use the restored models to compute accurate cross-entropies:

```
for k, _ in enumerate(models_ckpts):
  print(sess.run(models[k].xent, feed_dict={models[k].x_input: test_data,
                                            models[k].y_input: test_labels}))
```

I then declare a gradient of the first model's cross-entropy with respect to the inputs (e.g. to compute adversarial examples:

```
with tf.variable_scope('model_000'):
  grad = tf.gradients(models[0].xent, models[0].x_input)[0]
```

When evaluating these gradients as follows, I get an error

```
_grad = sess.run(grad, feed_dict={models[0].x_input: train_data,
                                  models[0].y_input: train_labels})

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

6 frames
InvalidArgumentError: Node 'gradients/model_000/input/map/while_grad/model_000/input/map/while_grad': Connecting to invalid output 6 of source node model_000/input/map/while which has 6 outputs. Try using tf.compat.v1.experimental.output_all_intermediates(True).
```

When I try to re-evaluate the cross-entropies I was able to compute earlier I continue to get he same error.

```
for k, _ in enumerate(models_ckpts):
  print(sess.run(models[k].xent, feed_dict={models[k].x_input: test_data,
                                            models[k].y_input: test_labels}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the gradients together with the models prior to restoring the variables makes the error go away:

```
from model import Model
models, gradients = [], []
for k, path in enumerate(models_ckpts):
  with tf.variable_scope('model_%03i' % k):
    models.append(Model(mode='eval'))
    gradients.append(tf.gradients(models[0].xent, models[0].x_input)[0])
```